# Using React in existing web forms applications

Tags: reactjs

I am having trouble understanding on how to add react to existing application. 
From React official documentation and from multiple blogs I read I am very confused by now. 
In my case I have an application written in web forms but acting as SPA and uses web methods and not native post backs. 
I use jQuery in general on client side and call web methods with ajax calls and everything works fine with that approach.

Recently I started to dive into React and have a good understanding with concept and coding but not in deployment. 
I want to start rewriting the current application by adding React components to existing site views and I don't understand what 
is the correct approach. So the questions are:

1. Can React be used without transpiling? Is it the correct way to go?
2. What scripts should I include in output html if at all? I tried the
   create-react-app, but this is a full template   and currently I don't
   think I need that.

Comment: I have the exact same problem in 2023 (never to old to learn). I'm looking to also start converting an Asp.Net website, that has lots of JS code that render a SPA on the client (so the Asp.Net is only for pre-render basically). But I'm wondering how to get VS2022 (not Code) to transpile the JSX files without using a completely new website template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For getting started with you just need to install, react & react-dom. Thats it. Start creating components and render with :

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return React.createElement('div', null, `Hello ${this.props.toWhat}`);
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(Hello, {toWhat: 'World'}, null),
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

But writing react components without JSX is not ideally preferred, hence you might need [babel-preset-react](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-react/) to transpile JSX to JS. That too is optional if you stick to writing [React without JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html). The same code above can be written in JSX as :

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>Hello {this.props.toWhat}</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello toWhat="World" />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Other than that you do not need anything to get started.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That part I got, what I am having trouble with, is what do I include in HTML file in order to render that? I do intent to use JSX as well.

Comment: Babel is good enough to generate final javascript for one single file. But for a large app with multiple components you would surely need a bundler. Popular ones are webpack, parcel, rollup etc which will generate a final javascript bundle from given an entry point. I would suggest starting with webpack.